# Comparing performance of different regexes, clarification needed

Tags: java, regex

Consider 3 regex expressions designed to remove non Latin characters from the string.

```
    String x = "some†¥¥¶¶ˆ˚˚word";

    long now = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(x.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""));     // 5ms
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - now);

    now = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(x.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", ""));    // 2ms
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - now);

    now = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(x.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]*", ""));    // <1ms
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - now);
```

All 3 produce the same result with vastly difference performance metrics.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is slower because the regex matches each non-latin character individually, so `replaceAll` operates on each characters individually.

The other patterns match the whole sequence of non-latin characters, so `replaceAll` can replace the whole sequence in one go.  I can't explain the performance difference between these two, though.  Probably something to do with the difference in handling `*` and `+` in the regex engine.

Comment: What @Andrew Cooper said, the difference between * and + is because the + has to do a little more looking ahead to make sure the pattern doesn't occur more than once, so it'll be a little slower

Answer (score 1):

The last one will replace empty strings with empty strings (unless that is optimized away, I do not know the compiler) which seems a bit unnecessary... ;-)

The first one will search much more times than the second if non-latin chars are adjecent. Otherwise not. So I guess the time for 1 and 2 might be roughly the same on some texts and longer for 1 on other texts.